# (Replit) Nix: How do I add a package to .nix?

Tags: nix

## Edit: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70598394/17825124)

---

I have a python script, and I need to run the script by running `python3 myscript.py`, however I get this message:

```
python3: command not installed. Multiple versions of this command were found in Nix.
```

And then when choosing the .out, python starts.

I found out I need to add python3 to .nix so that nix can automatically run python39Full if I type `python3`, in order to skip the message above.

```
Add 'python39Full' to replit.nix if you want to install 'python3' in this repl.
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to add a package to .nix, so can anyone please tell me how to add a package to .nix? thanks.

(In case you need to see the .nix file)

**replit.nix**

```
{ pkgs }: {
    deps = [
        pkgs.bashInteractive
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately, I have found a way to add packages to .nix (at least on replit):

---

If you would like to skip the following message:

```
python3: command not installed. Multiple versions of this command were found in Nix.
Select one to run (or press Ctrl-C to cancel):
> 
qtile.out
python39Full.out
python38Full.out
python3Minimal.out
python310.out
python37Full.out
python37.out
python38.out
sourcehut.python.out
python36.out
```

---

1. Get the package name you would like nix to automatically choose (I will use python39Full.out in my case)

---

2. Open the .nix file, which would look something like this:

**replit.nix**

```hs
{ pkgs }: {
    deps = [
        pkgs.bashInteractive
    ];
}
```

---

3. Add the package name to .nix, so the .nix would now look something like this:

**replit.nix**

```
{ pkgs }: {
    deps = [
        pkgs.bashInteractive
        python39Full.out
    ];
}
```

---

4. Add 'pkgs.' in the beginning of the package name, and remove '.out' from the package name, so the .nix file is now:

**replit.nix**

```
{ pkgs }: {
    deps = [
        pkgs.bashInteractive
        pkgs.python39Full
    ];
}
```

---

5. Save the file, and the next time you run `python3`, nix will not ask you everytime and it will automatically start python 3.9 for you.

**Demo**

```
john@doe:~$ python3 
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jun 28 2021, 08:57:49) 
[GCC 10.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```